# Attempting to extract numbers from text data, but re.findall() doesn't find anything

Tags: python

My objective is to write a program using regex that reads through a text file, and pulls out the numbers (as strings, then converts to integers) but I'm clearly missing some crucial element of this code. Here's what I have so far:

```
import re

#read the file
name = input('Input file name:')
handle = open(name)

#look for integers usings re.findall() / '[0-9]+'
y = re.findall('[0-9]+',handle)
print(y)
```

and it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "regexnumbers.py", line 8, in <module>
    y = re.findall('[0-9]+',handle)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

which to be honest doesn't make much sense to me as a beginner dev!

Comment: You have to read the text from the file: `y = re.findall('[0-9]+',handle.read())`

Comment: `handle` isn't a string. It's an object to read data from. Use `handle.read()` to get a string.

Comment: `open()` does not return the contents of the file. You need to read the contents from `handle` as a string before using `findAll`

Comment: The above mentioned + remember to close the find after usage!

Comment: thank you all! I figured it had to be something embarrassingly simple ha

Comment: @offeltoffel what does that do? that makes sense from an operational point but re: coding I don't understand

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_close.htm

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed a pass a string or buffer to `re.findall` but you're passing a file object -- `handle`, hence the error.

You can read all the file at once by using the `read()` method on the file object:

```
re.findall('[0-9]+',handle.read())
```

But if your file is large, a better approach would to read the file line by line (as the file object is an iterator) and use generator expression (or list comprehension) to refer the results:

```
matches = (re.findall('[0-9]+', line) for line in handle)
```

and then you can join up the matches iterator using `itertools.chain`:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(matches)
itertools.chain(*matches)
```

calling `list` on it would get you the result as a list:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matches))
```

If you need simple iteration over the results, no need to convert into a list.

Now, after the operation you need to close the file object to make sure the file descriptor it refers to is closed properly and the resources are released:

```
handle.close()
```

But a better and *idiomatic* way would be to use a context manager that does the job of closing automatically for you:

```
with open('file.txt') as handle:
    matches = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(re.findall('[0-9]+', line) for line in handle))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you're not doing the best way, but essentially it boils down to this:

For reading a file, the best construct would be:

```
with open('file') as filehandler:
    file_contents = filehandler.readlines()
```

This will read the contents of the file into a list (array if you will) and importantly, as the paragraph ends, closes the file. Then you can iterate through lines (each line as one list item) and do the regex statements on each.

The problem with your code is that you are passing an object (the file handler itself) to the re module. Hence the TypeError